# SQL Server Convert Rows Into Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this with 145.695 rows.

| SERVER | TAPE |
| --- | --- |
| ACS08 | M00030L3 |
| ACS08 | M00253L3 |
| ACS09 | M00580L3 |
| ACS09 | M00602L3 |
| ACS10 | M00580L4 |
| ACS10 | M00602L5 |
| ACS10 | M00602L7 |

Now I want to reach a target table structure like this:

| ACS08 | ACS09 | ACS10 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M00030L3 | M00580L3 | M00580L4 |
| M00253L3 | M00602L3 | M00602L5 |
|  |  | M00602L7 |

I need help because I dont know how can I do.

Comment: Do the column names change depending on the values? Or are they always the same? Or can we use `Server1,Server2,Server3`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic pivot to get the desired results.

First we need to generate the dynamic columns based on the [SERVER] column values and then `pivot` the values as per the requirement:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ QUOTENAME([SERVER])
                     FROM T FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');   --XML way of getting the column values

SET @query = 'SELECT '+@cols+' from 
                (
                    SELECT [SERVER], [TAPE], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SERVER] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as RN --We need to add a unique number to select all rows while doing aggregation for the PIVOT
                    FROM T
                )x 
                PIVOT (max([TAPE]) for [SERVER] in ('+@cols+')
            ) PVT';

EXECUTE (@query);
```

Please find the db<>fiddle [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ccbe47a3e4ef2c4abef8a560b1abe402).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(max), @Sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT 
    @Columns = 
        STRING_AGG(
            'MAX(CASE [Server] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME([Server], '''') + ' THEN [Tape] END) AS ' + QUOTENAME([Server]), 
            ','
        ) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY [Server]) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT [Server] FROM T GROUP BY [Server]
) S;

SET @Sql =
    'SELECT ' + @Columns + ' FROM 
        (SELECT [Server], [Tape], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SERVER] ORDER BY [Server]) as RN FROM T) S 
    GROUP BY RN'

EXEC(@Sql);
```

Note: `STRING_AGG()` is supported on SQL Server 2017 and later.